How can I achieve the same effect as ROW_NUMBER when using pagination?
I want to add count of rows per group of one of the columns. It works fine with regular queries, but not with pagination because each page starts the count from 0.
For example, I have the following table:
id | category_id | item_id | created_at
---|-------------|---------|-----------
 7 |      11     |   106   | 2024-05-06
 6 |      3      |   102   | 2024-05-06
 5 |      11     |   101   | 2024-05-05
 4 |      9      |   98    | 2024-05-04
 3 |      3      |   97    | 2024-05-03
 2 |      1      |   91    | 2024-05-02
 1 |      11     |   89    | 2024-05-01

And I want to count what order the item_id is in its category by the creation date.
For that I'm using the following query:
DB::('table')->select(
    table.*,
    DB::raw('ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY category_id ORDER BY created_at) as order')
)->get();

Which is the same as the following raw query:
SELECT table.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY category_id ORDER BY created_at) as order 
FROM table

And it results in:
id | category_id | item_id | created_at | order
---|-------------|---------|------------|-------
 7 |      11     |   106   | 2024-05-06 |    3
 6 |      3      |   102   | 2024-05-06 |    2
 5 |      11     |   101   | 2024-05-05 |    2
 4 |      9      |   98    | 2024-05-04 |    1
 3 |      3      |   97    | 2024-05-03 |    1
 2 |      1      |   91    | 2024-05-02 |    1  
 1 |      11     |   89    | 2024-05-01 |    1

But it won't work with pagination because each page has its own subset and the count starts from another row, the if for example I paginate the above table every 4 results, and end up with 2 pages, then page number 2 would result in the following:
id | category_id | item_id | created_at | order
---|-------------|---------|------------|-------
 7 |      11     |   106   | 2024-05-06 |    2
 6 |      3      |   102   | 2024-05-06 |    1
 5 |      11     |   101   | 2024-05-05 |    1

But I want it to be
id | category_id | item_id | created_at | order
---|-------------|---------|------------|-------
 7 |      11     |   106   | 2024-05-06 |    3
 6 |      3      |   102   | 2024-05-06 |    2
 5 |      11     |   101   | 2024-05-05 |    2

How can I do it?

Since pagination using the ->paginate() method uses LIMIT and OFFSET in the background, I don't think you can.
However, if you have no qualms about getting all the results and THEN returning only a subset of them with pagination, then you should be able to do it.
Caching the query's results could help as well.
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

// query
$ttl = 3600; // 60 * 60 seconds (1 hour)
$results = Cache::remember('query-results', $ttl, function () {
    return DB::('table')
        ->select(
            table.*,
            DB::raw('ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY category_id ORDER BY created_at) as order')
        )
        ->get();
});
// pagination
$page = request()->query('page', 1); // using the ?page= query parameter to get the current page
$perPage = 4;
$paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator(
    $results->forPage($page, $perPage)->values(),
    $results->count(),
    $perPage,
    $page,
);
  
// return response()->json(['data' => $paginator]);


I see, thank you! That might slow down this part of the app if I get all the results every time. Do you think it makes sense if I add an actual "counter" column like the order column,  which will be updated every time a row is inserted/deleted? So every time I insert a row for example, I'll check what was the last value then increase by one

Another possibility is you cache the query. And yeah, you could add a counter column like the order column if it makes sense for your application

I could try caching. How would you match the full query to just the paginated part? (Or you mean to completely replace the pagination method and implement it myself?)

The Query Builder's paginate method uses laravel's LengthAwarePaginator in the background, so there's no need to implement it. You can just instantiate it (I've edited my answer to show an example)

That's awesome, thank you. And now if I want to display the most up to date result, it means that for every update made to the table, I can delete the cache key so that it will re-query on the next reload?

Yup, that's it. Cache::forget('query-result'); on each insert/update/delete.
